# gitlab registry connection reset error 500

Tags: registry, gitlab

I'm configuring GitLab container registry, running the onmibus version 9.1.2 (CentOS build on RHEL7).

--Added for Clarity: This is Gitlab running on a RHEL7 server, not in a container.--

After we enable the container registry in GitLab and reconfigure, I can see the registry process running, but when I try to navigate to it in the GitLab gui, I get a 500 error.  production.log says this:

```
Started GET "/group/project/container_registry" for <ipaddr> at 2017-05-11 07:59:15 -0500
Processing by Projects::Registry::RepositoriesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"namespace_id"=>"CFAdmins", "project_id"=>"DefaultTest"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2015ms (ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)

Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Connection reset by peer):
  lib/container_registry/client.rb:19:in `repository_tags'
  app/models/container_repository.rb:36:in `manifest'
  app/models/container_repository.rb:41:in `tags'
  app/models/container_repository.rb:53:in `has_tags?'
  app/controllers/projects/registry/repositories_controller.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in ensure_root_container_repository!'
  app/controllers/projects/registry/repositories_controller.rb:36:in `tap'
  app/controllers/projects/registry/repositories_controller.rb:36:in `block in ensure_root_container_repository!'
  app/controllers/projects/registry/repositories_controller.rb:33:in `tap'
  app/controllers/projects/registry/repositories_controller.rb:33:in `ensure_root_container_repository!'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:93:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:16:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:10:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/request_context.rb:18:in `call'
```

This question: [setting gitlab with docker registry error 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801406/setting-gitlab-with-docker-registry-error-500) seems closest to what I'm experiencing, but it's not a perfect match.  In that case, it appears the OP is running a separate registry in a docker container and using GitLab as an auth endpoint for the registry.

Likewise: [setting up gitlab as docker container with docker registry showing error 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925220/setting-up-gitlab-as-docker-container-with-docker-registry-showing-error-500) is close, but doesn't match.  The presumptive answer there is that GitLab doesn't provide its own registry, but that contradicts the GitLab docs for the onmibus community edition, which doesn't indicate a requirement for an external registry. (see: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/container_registry.html#configure-container-registry-under-its-own-domain)

The gitlab-workhorse/current log lists that it returned a 500 error, but that's not terribly useful.  Nothing gets logged to registry/current, at all.

What else do I need to look at?

Cheers!
-juheimbu

Comment: Have you exposed the correct ports

Comment: I'm not running GitLab in a docker container, so I'm not sure that applies.

Comment: Why is the word "Docker" and "container" used so many times? Also, your linked examples are all docker related... maybe reword your question so it doesn't need to be read 10x to understand it

Comment: The linked examples were the closest I could find to my current situation, but they don't match exactly, which is why I need to ask a separate question about the issue.  To your point, though, I'll update to clarify what I'm talking about.  Thanks for the tip.